# Flushing iptables on RHEL7 causes the server to hang

Tags: rhel, iptables, freeze

When I run `iptables -F` on a RHEL 7 system, the server hangs and I have to reboot it. I want to flush rules frequently on the server; stopping the iptables service does not achieve the objective. Is there a way I can rectify this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the iptables services?

```
sudo yum install iptables-services
```

stop firewalld, the new iptables interface on EL7:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

Optionally, remove it:
    `sudo yum -y remove firewalld`

[a source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-firewalld-to-iptables-on-centos-7)

Comment: iptables-services is already installed. I will try uninstalling firewall and try